# Why does gdb always give "Program exited with code 01"?

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a `main.cpp` file and two .hpp files, one of which contains a set of classes and methods that I make modifications to. Compiling `main` is successful, but Running `main` results in `Segmentation Fault`. Following this [tutorial](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/), I used:

```
$ gdb main
(gdb) run
```

However, `(gdb) run` always produces the following regardless whether the .hpp file has bugs:

```
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Usage: viewer NODES_FILE TETS_FILE

Program exited with code 01.
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Comment: Well, what value is your `main()` returning?

Comment: What do you mean by "regardless of whether the .hpp file has bugs?"  Are you sure that your program is compiling at all?

Comment: the program compiles. One of the .hpp file launches XQuartz for display. Running main results in segmentation fault and also viewer displays an error dialogue box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try issuing these commands:

```
$ gdb main
(gdb) run nodes_file test_file
```

Filling in, of course, the correct values for the two parameters.